# Change specific icon through ternary operator map?

Tags: reactjs

I built a map through my `render` and I got everything working as intended however I found a small bug in my code where when I hit the edit button, it changes all the edit buttons through the map. How can I only change the edit icon for that specific map icon instead of it affecting all the others through my renders `map`?

Here is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';

import Headericons from '../common/header-icons';
import Header from '../common/header';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Moment from 'moment';
import { confirmAlert } from 'react-confirm-alert';
import Pagination from 'react-js-pagination';
import CKEditor from "react-ckeditor-component";

import ForumpageService from '../../services/forumService';
import appController from '../../controllers/appController';

import Footer from '../common/footer';

class Forumreplies extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.deleteReply = this.deleteReply.bind(this);
        this.pagination = this.pagination.bind(this);

        this.createEditor = this.createEditor.bind(this);
        this.destroyEditor = this.destroyEditor.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            topicId: 0,
            replyId: 0,
            userId: this.props.match.params.userid,
            isloggedinuserId: '',
            postDetails: {},
            repliesData: [],
            reply: '',
            errorMsg: '',
            isLoggedin: false,

            // CKeditor edit state
            showEditor: false,
        }
    }

    onChange(e) {
        //console.log("onChange fired with event info: ", e);
        var newContent = e.editor.getData();
        this.setState({
            reply: newContent
        })
        //console.log(this.state);
    }

    async onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (this.state.reply === '') {
            this.setState({ errorMsg: true })
        } else {
            // Insert reply
            const data = {
                userId: this.state.isloggedinuserId,
                reply: this.state.reply,
                topicId: this.state.topicId
            }
            const userReply = await ForumpageService.addReply(data)
            location.href = '/replies/' + this.props.match.params.topicid + '/user/' + this.props.match.params.userid + '/' + this.props.match.params.topic_name;
            //console.log(userReply);
        }
    }

    createEditor(replyeID){
        this.setState({showEditor: true})
        //console.log(e);
        if(!this.state.showEditor){
            // Create editor instance
            CKEDITOR.inline(replyeID);
        }
    }
    
    destroyEditor(destroyreplyeID){
        this.setState({showEditor: false})

        //console.log(destroyreplyeID);

        if (this.state.showEditor) {
            // Save & Destroy editor instance
            console.log(CKEDITOR.instances[destroyreplyeID].getData());
            CKEDITOR.instances[destroyreplyeID].destroy();
        }
    }

    

    render() {
        
            const repliesData = currentTopics.map((row, index) =>
                <div className="reply-container" key={index}>
                    {
                        row.reply_status == 0 ?
                        <div className="row" id="reply-messages-deleted">
                            <div className="col-md-2" id="profile-info">
                                {<span>{row.userName}</span>}
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-8">
                                <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: row.reply_message}} />
                                <h3>This reply has been deleted.</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-2">
                                <p>{'Replied: ' + Moment.utc(row.created_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A')}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        :
                        <div className="row" id="reply-messages" key={index}>
                            <div className="col-md-2" id="profile-info">
                                {<span>{row.userName}</span>}
                            </div>
                                <div className="col-md-8" 
                                    suppressContentEditableWarning
                                    contentEditable="true"
                                    >
                                    <p id={"editor_" + row.reply_id} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: row.reply_message }} />
                                </div>
                            <div className="col-md-2">
                                <p>{'Replied: ' + Moment.utc(row.created_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A')}</p>



                                {
                                    this.state.showEditor == false
                                    ? <span>{this.state.isloggedinuserId == row.reply_user_id && this.state.isLoggedin == true
                                    ? <i className="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true" onClick={this.createEditor.bind(this, "editor_" + row.reply_id)} title="Edit this Reply"></i>
                                    : null}</span> 
                                    : <span>{this.state.isloggedinuserId == row.reply_user_id && this.state.isLoggedin == true 
                                    ? <i className="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true" onClick={this.destroyEditor.bind(this, "editor_" + row.reply_id)} title="Update this Reply"></i> 
                                    : null}
                                    </span>
                                }
                                {this.state.isloggedinuserId == row.reply_user_id && this.state.isLoggedin == true ? <i className="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true" title="Delete this Reply" onClick={this.deleteReply.bind(this, row.reply_id)}></i> : null}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            )

        return (
            <div className="fluid-container">
                <div className="container" id="forum-replies">
                    <Link className="btn btn-primary" id="previouspage" to="/forumpage">&#8592; Go Back</Link>
                    <div className="row" id="question-user">
                        <div className="col-md-2" id="question-info">
                            <span>{this.state.postDetails.userName}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-8">
                            <h1>{this.state.postDetails.topic_name}</h1>
                            <p>{this.state.postDetails.topic_message}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-2">
                            <p>{'Asked: ' + Moment.utc(this.state.postDetails.created_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A')}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   {repliesData}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Forumreplies;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing a boolean, you can store the row id of the active editor instead:

```
setState({ activeEditor: row.id })
```

Set it to `null` when no editor is active.

Then in the `.map` you can check for the matching id:

```
this.state.activeEditor == row.id
```

If multiple active editors are allowed, then you can use an object/array/`Set` to store the list of active editors in the state.

Comment: Okay thank you let me try this and I'll get back to you appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm not sure where I would setState of the activeEditor would I have to move my render to a method instead?

Comment: How are you setting your `showEditor` state currently? Can you post your code related to that?

Comment: I edited my code. There is a lot of it so I tried to only show the relevant info pertaining to your last comment. I believe I'm initially setting it to nothing but then I'm setting it to true or false based off the ternary operator conditions for the methods. of editing a reply and deleting one.

Comment: Replace `this.setState({ showEditor: true })` with `this.setState({ activeEditor: replyeID })` and `this.state.showEditor == false` with `this.state.activeEditor == 'editor_' + row.reply_id` (might want to get rid of that `editor_`).

Comment: Thank you i got it but I had to make a little modification to my code. I had to set the destroy method state of `activeeditor` to nothing since it doesn't know what row.id is until it gets to the create method.